# SBT Build Fails for Scalaz library

Tags: scala, sbt

I have a sbt application which results in the following error when run as a docker build:

```
[info] Resolving net.java#jvnet-parent;4 ...
[error] Server access Error: Connection timed out (Connection timed out) url=http://dl.bintray.com/scalaz/releases/net/java/jvnet-parent/4/jvnet-parent-4.jar
```

I'm sure that I need to add some resolvers, but just not sure which one. Also strangely, the path to jvnet from scalaz is scary!

Any ideas? My Scala version is 2.11.7!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well actually I do not have a dependency to scalaz, so I just had to replace the scalaz resolver in my build.sbt:

```
resolvers += "sonatype-releases" at "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/public/"
//resolvers += "scalaz-bintray" at "http://dl.bintray.com/scalaz/releases"
```